# Query parameters are gone missing from the url when the url loads in angular 6

Tags: routes, angular6

The url is loading with out query parameters

```
{path: 'user', component: usercomponent}

https://www.(website).com/user?id=6
```

When the url opens the query parameters are gone missing and the url simply loads like.

```
https://www.(website).com/user
```

How can i fix this issue our application is developed using angualar 6. Can you please give any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get user detail according id please use following 
       { path: 'user/:id',      component: usercomponent },

Comment: I have used that also. But my problem here is . In my router i am using resolve like . {path: 'user/:id' , component:usercomponent, resolve:{ country: getcountry} }. So the first url will be like https://www.(website).com/user?id=1 --> then url will need be like https://www.(website).com/user/{{country-lang}}?id=1 . but when ever i am entering the url with https://www.(website).com/user?id=1 the qurey param is missing. and the url is becoming like https://www.(website).com/user/{{country-lang}}.

Comment: if you want to following url:  website.com/user-{{country-lang}}?id=1 Please set .    router_url= 'user-eng/:id'  { path:router_url, component: usercomponent },